# Gathering numbers from RGB string

Tags: javascript

So on my webpage I have inputs which expect to get from user string like this

```
rgb(0, 128, 192)
```

on submit I want to gather numbers from this string and console it out.

```
console.log(first_number);
console.log(second_number);
console.log(third_number);
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a simple regex `/\d+/g` to match the numbers:

```js
var string = "rgb(0, 128, 192)";

var numbers = string.match(/\d+/g);     // get the numbers

if(numbers && numbers.length === 3) {   // if there is numbers in the string, and there is exactly 3
  console.log(numbers);                 // log them
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `rgb(` and `)` from the string, split it by `,` and then parse the parts as ints:

```
function getRGBFromString(str){
    var parts = str.slice(4,-1).split(',')
    return [parseInt(parts[0]),parseInt(parts[1]),parseInt(parts[2])]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that like so:

```js
function getRGBNumbers(rgbString) {
    var regex = /rgb\(([0-9]{1,3})\,[ ]?([0-9]{1,3})\,[ ]?([0-9]{1,3})\)/;
    var match = regex.exec(rgbString);

    // Invalid rgb string
    if (match === null) {
        return null;
    }

    // Remove first element of the array that contains all numbers
    match.shift();

    return match;
}

var rgbNumber = getRGBNumbers("rgb(0, 128, 192)");
console.log(rgbNumber[0]); // 0
console.log(rgbNumber[1]); // 128
console.log(rgbNumber[2]); // 192

var rgbNumber2 = getRGBNumbers("rgb(5,100,255)");
console.log(rgbNumber2[0]); // 5
console.log(rgbNumber2[1]); // 100
console.log(rgbNumber2[2]); // 255

var rgbNumber3 = getRGBNumbers("rgb(5,255)");
if (rgbNumber3 === null) {
    console.log("Invalid input string");
}
```